# Nested NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

Suppose that we have the given simple integral expression

$$
\int_{-5}^{5} x \int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{\int_{0}^{z} -y dy} dz dx
$$

Writing this out in *Mathematica* we obtain:

```
Integrate[x Integrate[Exp[Integrate[-y, {y, 0, z}]], {z, -∞, x}], {x, -5., 5}]
30.0795
```

#### Question:

Is it possible to do a numerical integration on this expression by using `NIntegrate`?

A very naive attempt gives us the following errors:

```
NIntegrate[x NIntegrate[Exp[NIntegrate[-y, {y, 0, z}]], {z, -∞, x}], {x, -5, 5}]
```

> NIntegrate::nlim: y = z is not a valid limit of integration

Notice that we want everything to be a numerical integration, this includes the inner integrals.

The problem is that one of the `NIntegrate`s is an argument to the exponential function and this does not allow us to write the double integral with only one `NIntegrate` as mentioned in [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalIntegration.html)

#### Motivation

I'm trying to evaluate an expression that is too complicated for Mathematica to do symbolically and it is composed on integrals of the kind mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this question, I have a problem exactly like yours where the bounds of the inner integral are dependent on the current value of the outer integral and it was blowing up in my face. This helped a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can always separate your inner integrals, convert them to functions and use in `NIntegrate`:

```
i1[z_?NumericQ] := i1[z] = NIntegrate[-y, {y, 0, z}]
i2[x_?NumericQ] := i2[x] = NIntegrate[Exp[i1[z]], {z, -∞, x}]
NIntegrate[x i2[x], {x, -5., 5}]
(* 30.0795 *)
```

Comment: This seems to be working on my actual problem. I'm still waiting on the result. Thank you.

Comment: Took a while but it finished. :)

Comment: @R.M. Could one use `N[Integrate[...]]` in case some of the inner integrals have an analytic solution ? If not, `N[Integrate[...]]=NIntegrate[...]` anyways.

Comment: @b.gatessucks If the inner ones have an analytic solution that _also_ evaluates quickly, then yes, doing so might be worthwhile. But I've come across some integrals that have a nice analytical solution, but take a long time to compute whereas `NIntegrate` gives it instantly. Also, `N@Integrate` will give the same result as `NIntegrate` only if the function is well behaved within the default options in `NIntegrae` (e.g., not highly oscillatory, requiring increased precisions/recursions, etc). So `N@Integrate` only applies `N` to the result, whereas `NIntegrate` will use different algorithms

Comment: Thank you for this answer it has solved my problem perfectly (and saved me the trouble of asking a question to boot :) ) Thanks again.

Comment: Curiously it works only with ?NumericQ. So, it looks like NIntegrate gives numerical values only if the check ?NumericQ is inserted, which looks strange to me. Does anyone has an explanation why it is like this?

Comment: Related you may help ; ) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157158/

Comment: Note that if you have defined a function without the ?NumericQ, you need to clear the function definition (easiest method is to restart Kernel) after adding the ?NumericQ, or it will not work.

Answer (score 21):

It is possible like so for example:

```
ClearAll[fn];
fn[z_?NumericQ] := Exp[NIntegrate[-y, {y, 0, z}]];

NIntegrate[x fn[z], {x, -5, 5}, {z, -∞, x}]

(*  30.0795  *)
```

but it takes a while to compute.

I used the ability of `NIntegrate` to handle non-rectangular domains, which is very powerful but not widely known and / or appreciated, it seems. Note that the answers which numericalize all dimensions separately may not pick the optimal integration grid in multi-dimensional case, in which class of cases (and this includes the case in question) this form may generally work better.

Comment: Related you may help ; ) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157158/