# NIntegrate inside NSum

Tags: numerical-integration

Consider the following function with a numerical integration:

```
BDMAF[n_, γ_, x_, c_] := 
 Module[{K1 = EllipticK[1/Sqrt[1 + γ^2]], 
   E1 = EllipticE[1/Sqrt[1 + γ^2]], y0},
  y0 = ((π^2 (IntegerPart[x + 1] - x + n))/(2 K1 E1))^(1/2);
  Exp[-y0^2] NIntegrate[
    Exp[y^2] Sin[(n + IntegerPart[x + 1])/2 π + c y]^2, {y, 0, y0}]
  ]
```

that works perfectly if all parameters are explicitly defined:

```
BDMAF[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

> 0.0391914

I need to calculate the infinite sum over n. Naive approach gives

```
NSum[BDMAF[n, 1, 1, 1], {n, 0, ∞}]
```

> NIntegrate::nlim: y = 1.38268 Sqrt[1. +n]  is not a valid limit of
>   integration. >>

Following the answer to the question about [nested NIntegrate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10533/nested-nintegrate), I tried to redefine BDMAF as follows:

```
BDMAF[n_?NumericQ, γ_, x_, c_] := BDMAF[n, γ, x, c] = 
  Module[{K1 = EllipticK[1/Sqrt[1 + γ^2]], 
    E1 = EllipticE[1/Sqrt[1 + γ^2]], y0},
   y0 = ((π^2 (IntegerPart[x + 1] - x + n))/(2 K1 E1))^(1/2);
   Exp[-y0^2] NIntegrate[
     Exp[y^2] Sin[(n + IntegerPart[x + 1])/2 π + c y]^2, {y, 0, y0}]
   ]
```

The problem remains, but I receive another error message:

```
NSum[BDMAF[n, 1, 1, 1], {n, 0, ∞}]
```

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand BDMAF(n,1,1,1) has evaluated to
>   non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with
>   boundaries (15.   4.64782*10^14). >>

How BDMAF function should be defined?

Comment: The problem is your integral. Try to evaluate `BDMAF[4.64782*10^14, 1, 1, 1]` and see, why it results in a non-numerical value.

Comment: You're sure this sum of yours converges? Some experimentation with various settings of `NSum[]` and `NIntegrate[]` are yielding somewhat conflicting results on my end...

Comment: `Table[BDMAF[n, 1, 1, 1], {n, 0, 120}] // ListLinePlot` produces this http://i.stack.imgur.com/P0sRg.png which as @J.M. points out suggests slow convergence if any.

Comment: Thanks. I rechecked the derivations and figured out that instead of Sin^2 there should be Cos^2. In this case the sum converges faster and everything works. It is strange that Mathematica did not show the message about the sum convergence.

Comment: @StanislavKruchinin you might want to write an answer to your question then.

Comment: "It is strange that Mathematica did not show the message about the sum convergence." - the built-in convergence checks are not entirely foolproof, and there will always be troublesome sums whose convergence/divergence will not be readily apparent to *Mathematica*.

Comment: A plot of the partial sums has me skeptical that your sum is convergent even after replacing the sine with cosine: `SetAttributes[BDMAF, Listable]; ListPlot[Accumulate[BDMAF[Range[0, 180], 1, 1, 1]]]` Where did this problem of yours come from, exactly?

Comment: The problem was in the invalid testing series, that did not converge. Another sample series `NSum[Exp[-Pi n] BDMAF[n, 1, 1, 1], {n, 0, Infinity}]` which is closer to the original expression that I actually need converges perfectly, and works well with `NIntegrate` inside `NSum`. Case closed. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Could you maybe answer your own question, so that this does not go unanswered?

Answer (score 3):

Problem was in the non-convergent sum. This example with the new sum works good:

```
BDMAF[n_?NumericQ, \[Gamma]_, x_, c_] := BDMAF[n, \[Gamma], x, c] = 
  Module[{K1 = EllipticK[1/Sqrt[1 + \[Gamma]^2]], 
    E1 = EllipticE[1/Sqrt[1 + \[Gamma]^2]], y0},
   y0 = ((\[Pi]^2 (IntegerPart[x + 1] - x + n))/(2 K1 E1))^(1/2);
   Exp[-y0^2] NIntegrate[
     Exp[y^2] Sin[(n + IntegerPart[x + 1])/2 \[Pi] + c y]^2, {y, 0, y0}]
   ]

NSum[Exp[-Pi n] BDMAF[n, 1, 1, 1], {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

Thanks for your attention.