# Nested NIntegrate - NIntegrate::inum: - error

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the problem quite similar as in:
[Nested NIntegrate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10533/nested-nintegrate)
I define two functions:

```
r[x_] := Evaluate[q[x] /. NDSolve[{q'[t] == 0.0001 + (-1 + I*1 + q[t])*q[t],q[0] == 0}, q, 
                                  {t, 0, 50}]]

fn[k_?NumericQ] := Exp[8*NIntegrate[r[s]*Exp[2*beta*1] + 8*r[s], {s, 0, k}]]

beta=1
```

When I want to know the value of:

```
NIntegrate[fn[k], {k, 0, 5}]
```

I obtain following error:

> NIntegrate::inum: "Integrand fn[k] is not numerical at {k} = {0.03978659976289378`}."

Adding `?NumericQ` to r[k_] I obtain error:

> NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand fn[k] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,5}}"

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your differential equation can be solved analytically

```
eqns = {q'[t] == 10^-4 + (-1 + I*1 + q[t])*q[t], q[0] == 0};

sol = DSolve[eqns, q, t][[1]]

(* Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may 
   not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

{q -> Function[{t}, 1/100 ((50-50 I)+Sqrt[1+5000 I] Tan[1/100 (Sqrt[1+5000 I] t+
  100 ArcTan[(249950/25000001+(250050 I)/25000001) Sqrt[1+5000 I]])])]} *)
```

Verifying that `sol` satisfies `eqns`

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)

r[x_] = q[x] /. sol;

beta = 1;

fn[k_?NumericQ] := Exp[8*NIntegrate[r[s]*Exp[2*beta*1] + 8*r[s], {s, 0, k}]]

NIntegrate[fn[k], {k, 0, 5}]

(* 5.07422 + 0.0503325 I *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your integrand numeric!

```
r[x_] := q[x] /.NDSolve[{q'[t] == 0.0001 + (-1 + I*1 + q[t])*q[t], q[0] == 0}, q, {t, 0, 50}][[1]]
beta = 1;
fn[k_?NumericQ] := Exp[8*NIntegrate[r[s]*Exp[2*beta*1] + 8*r[s], {s, 0, k}]]
NIntegrate[fn[k], {k, 0, 5}]
(*
5.07423 + 0.0503328 I
*)
```

Comment: I still get an error :NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand fn[k] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,5}}. "

Comment: Sorry, that's works, but the only difference which I see is a definition of r[x]. What means at the end of it [[1]]? (I'm not very good in Mathematica)

Comment: @Agnieszka Take a look at `Part[]` in the help