# Nested Nintegrate - two variable limits of integral

Tags: numerical-integration

This is, so to say, the next part of the question: [Nested NIntegrate - NIntegrate::inum: - error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19888/nested-nintegrate-nintegrateinum-error)

Now I define three functions:

```
r[x_] := q[x] /. NDSolve[{q'[t] == 0.0001 + (-1 + I*1 + q[t])*q[t], q[0] == 0}, q, 
   {t, 0, 50}][[1]]

beta = 1;

fn[k_, t_?NumericQ] := Exp[8*NIntegrate[r[s]*Exp[2*beta*1] + 8*r[s], {s, t, k}]]

f00[x_, t_, p_] := 
   p*Exp[-8*NIntegrate[r[s]*Exp[2*beta*1] - 8*r[s], {s, t, x}]] + 
   8*Exp[-8*NIntegrate[r[s]*Exp[2*beta*1] - 8*r[s], {s, t, x}]]*
      NIntegrate[Exp[2*beta*1]*fn[y, t], {y, t, x}]
```

When I evaluate

```
f00[20, 2, 0.5]
```

I obtain the error:

> NIntegrate::nlim: s = y is not a valid limit of integration.

The difference between the first question is now both limits of the integral in the definition of `fn` are variables, and I have to evaluate the integral

```
NIntegrate[Exp[2*beta*1]*fn[y, t], {y, t, x}]
```

What I can do?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only change I needed was

```
fn[k_?NumericQ,t_?NumericQ] := Exp[8*NIntegrate[r[s]*Exp[2*beta*1] + 8*r[s], {s, t, k}]]
```

After this change, Mathematica returned no error.

Please note, that your original version already returned the same results although the error message was printed.