# Nested NIntegrate of vector function

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to perform a nested integration where the upper limit of the inner integral depends on the value of the outer integral, like in this question: [Nested NIntegrate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10533/nested-nintegrate).

Just like the linked question, my function can not be symbolically integrated, however, in my case the function is a vector (representing a force field in 3D) instead of a scalar.

Wolfram Technical Support confirmed that `NIntegrate` does not support integration of a list of numerical values. Therefore the answer to the Nested NIntegrate question does not directly work.

I have considered simply creating three numeric functions that each calculate the force and take a different component of it, then integrating each separately. I could also create three interpolations and integrate them separately, which speeds up the calculation at the expense of accuracy.

Is there a better way to do this?