# NIntegrate over a list of functions

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics, matlab

This question is the result of these other two questions. Question [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77503/slow-exponential-evaluation-over-lists?lq=1) and [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77333/slow-evaluation-of-nintegrate-when-used-as-a-pure-function). I thought it would be better to ask a new question rather than deleting previous one.

I think When `NIntegrate` is used on lists it becomes slow. I give the integrand a list of data points and hence integrand is a list of functions. When the number of elements are below 20, Mathematica is either as fast as or faster than Matlab. Yet, when the number of elements increases Mathematica gets slow:

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]
shaxis = Table[1.0*i, {i, 1, 20}];
Total[NIntegrate[shaxis/(x^3 + 10), {x, 0, Infinity}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.039000, 54.7079717948704}

```
laxis = Table[1.0*i, {i, 1, 2046}];
Total[NIntegrate[laxis/(x^3 + 10), {x, 0, Infinity}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.058000, 545537.7346865428}

Both Matlab and Mathematica, in this case, use global adaptive quadrature method. The performance as a function of number of elements of the list depends on the integrand too. In general, it seems it is the length of the list which is the factor making Mathematica slow.

Matlab's documentation about `integral`:

> q = integral(fun,xmin,xmax) numerically integrates function fun from xmin to xmax using global adaptive quadrature and default error tolerances.

### Edit

I think the problem is that Matlab uses vectorization and hence uses all of the CPU cores available, but Mathematica won't do the same. If I use a very long list in Matlab, it uses all the cores but not Mathematica.

Matlab's code:

```
clc
clear all;
f = @(x,t)  t./((x.^3) + 10);
t = 1:0.001:2000;
tic
sum(integral(@(x) f(x,t),0,Inf,'ArrayValued',true))
toc
```

In Matlab code I used 'ArrayValued' to enable the integrand to receive a vector. 
I have the same problem, not using all the cores, in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78278/ndsolve-in-mathematica-wont-use-all-the-cores-avaiable) too.
There again Matlab uses vectorization.

Comment: Assuming you've got the timings reversed, they are proportional to the length of the lists, which is what I would expect.  Are you saying that Matlab invokes some sort of optimization on long lists?  (BTW, I'm assuming this is a toy example, as there are much more efficient approaches to this particular integration problem.)

Comment: The timings were interchanged. I edited that. The integral is also a toy model.
I have not worked with Matlab. Because of this problem recently I started to use it, so I don't know what Matlab does that makes it faster on this one. I checked the results of both and they are the same.

Comment: Why don't you use `Total@Table[NIntegrate[i/(10 + x^3), {x, 0, Infinity}], {i, laxis}]`?

Comment: @Jinxed On my system your code is even slower. Even if I use parallelization it's still considerably slower than Matlab.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I updated the question.

Comment: I think it'll be better if you can add some screenshots etc. to illustrate the speed difference.

Comment: See this answer for a method: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126041/4999

Answer (score 8):

#### `NIntegrate` does each integral separately

This has been observed before:
[NIntegrate piecewise vector function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45763/nintegrate-piecewise-vector-function), [Nested NIntegrate of vector function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51704/nested-nintegrate-of-vector-function).  It is also clear from the following `BenchmarkPlot`:

```
int[n_] := Block[{shaxis},
   shaxis = Table[1.0*i, {i, 1, n}];
   NIntegrate[shaxis/(x^3 + 10), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}]];
BenchmarkPlot[int, # &, 2^Range[4, 11], "IncludeFits" -> True, 
 TimeConstraint -> 20.`]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would not know why there has been no interest in developing such functionality for `NIntegrate`.  `NDSolve` has it.

#### Using `NDSolve` instead

`NDSolve` uses a local estimate of the error to control the step size.  It is not going to be as robust as the global adaptive strategy of `NIntegrate`, but it can do a pretty good job.  On the OP's test example, it does quite well, but those functions are similar and relatively easy to integrate.

We need to remap the infinite interval `{x, 0, Infinity}` to a finite one.  The substitution `x -> t/(1 - t)` pulls it back to `{t, 0, 1}`.  As it is not as good at estimating error, I had to fiddle with `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` to get as accurate a solution as possible.  This is a drawback to this method.  If you set them higher, `NDSolveValue` complains and stops integration before reaching the end.  Below we'll compare it with the default `NDSolve` settings, `NIntegrate` timings and the exact solution.

```
shaxis = Table[1.0*i, {i, 1, 2046}];
ClearAll[df];
df[t_] = shaxis/(x^3 + 10) Dt[x] /. x -> t/(1 - t) /. Dt[t] -> 1 // Simplify;
ndvals = NDSolveValue[
    {a'[t] == df[t], a[0] == ConstantArray[0, Length@shaxis]},
    a[1], {t, 0, 1},
    PrecisionGoal -> 16, AccuracyGoal -> 11]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*   {0.349559, Null}   *)

ndvals0 = NDSolveValue[
    {a'[t] == df[t], a[0] == ConstantArray[0, Length@shaxis]},
    a[1], {t, 0, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*   {0.240336, Null}   *)

nivals = NIntegrate[
    shaxis/(x^3 + 10), {x, 0, Infinity}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*   {7.49675, Null}   *)

(* xzczd's solution *)
NIntegrate[shaxis/(x^3 + 10), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", 
      "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*   {2.29383, Null}   *)

exact = shaxis Integrate[1/(x^3 + 10), {x, 0, Infinity}];
```

With the special precision/accuracy settings, the `NDSolve` solutions are a little better than the default `NIntegrate` ones. (Again, though, the integrands are not numerically difficult.)

```
ListPlot[Log10@{Abs[(ndvals - exact)/exact], Abs[(nivals - exact)/exact]}]
```

The default `NDSolve` has 8 digits of precision, which is the default goal:

```
{Norm[(ndvals0 - exact)]/Norm[exact],
 Norm[(ndvals - exact)]/Norm[exact],
 Norm[(nivals - exact)]/Norm[exact]}
(*  {6.57234*10^-8, 1.2117*10^-13, 4.61459*10^-13}  *)
```

#### Vector version of `NIntegrate`

We can easily adapt the implementation of a global adaptive strategy in [`tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#16672882) to handle vector integrands.  With a little refactoring, we can make take advantage of the built-in vectorization of *Mathematica* functions.  In this implementation, the integrand needs to be `Listable`.  On the integrand `df` above, it uses four cores (of the 4-core/8-virtual-core i7 on my Mac) typical of *Mathematica's* vectorized functions.

Of course this circumvents all the other nice features of `NIntegrate`, but it might be comparable to the Matlab function (of which I'm ignorant).

```
res = IStrategyGlobalAdaptive[df, {0, 1}, 10^-8]; // AbsoluteTiming
Norm[(res - exact)]/Norm[exact]
(*
  {0.952552, Null}
  1.28022*10^-15
*)
```

*Code:*

```
{absc, weights, errweights} = NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[5, MachinePrecision];

ClearAll[IRuleEstimate, IStrategyGlobalAdaptive];
IRuleEstimate[f_, a_, b_] :=
  (b - a) {weights, errweights}.Transpose[f[Rescale[absc, {0, 1}, {a, b}]]];

IStrategyGlobalAdaptive[f_, {aArg_, bArg_}, tol_] /; 
   MatrixQ[f[N@{aArg, bArg}], NumericQ] :=
  Module[{integral, error, regions, r1, r2, a = N[aArg], b = N[bArg], c},

   {integral, error} = IRuleEstimate[f, a, b];

   (* boundaries, integral, error *)
   regions = {{a, b, integral, error}};

   While[Norm[error] >= tol*Norm[integral],
    (* splitting of the region with the largest error *)
    {a, b} = regions[[-1, 1 ;; 2]]; c = (a + b)/2;

    (* integration of the left region *)
    {integral, error} = IRuleEstimate[f, a, c];
    r1 = {a, c, integral, error};

    (* integration of the right region *)
    {integral, error} = IRuleEstimate[f, c, b];
    r2 = {c, b, integral, error};

    (* sort the regions: the largest error is last *)
    regions = Join[Most[regions], {r1, r2}];
    regions = SortBy[regions, Norm@*Last];

    (* global integral and error vectors *)
    {integral, error} = Total[regions[[All, -2 ;;]]];
    ];

   integral
   ];
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0` (it's probably the "default setting" of *Matlab*, right?) and making use of parallelism gives me a **3X** speedup on my dual-core old laptop:

```
laxis = ParallelTable[1.0 i, {i, 1, 2046}];
Total[ParallelMap[
   NIntegrate[#/(x^3 + 10), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", 
       "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}] &, laxis]] // AbsoluteTiming
```