# More issues Integrate, NIntegrate, FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve a system of 3 non-linear equations using FindRoot and Integrate.  If I start FindRoot[] close to the right answer, it works well but returns a bunch of error messages first.

```
f[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := Exp[-(a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c)];
aa = FindRoot[Integrate[(x^{0, 2, 4})*f[x, a, b, c], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] - {1, 2, 10} // N, {a, .01}, {b, .15}, {c, 1.33}]

(*  NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand f[x,a,b,c] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all...   *)
(*  {a -> 0.0108063, b -> 0.141937, c -> 1.36499}  *)
```

But if I start a ways farther from the right answer, it give me pages of error messages and returns my starting values.  I actually ended up having to write a random-walk algorithm to get close enough to the right answer for FindRoot[] to finish the job.

The command that failed completely was this:

```
aa = FindRoot[NIntegrate[(x^{0, 2, 4})*f[x, a, b, c], {x, -Infinity,Infinity}] - {1, 2, 10} // N, {a, .1}, {b, .5}, {c, .33}]
```

My crude random-walk algorithm handled this starting point just fine.

So even though I got an answer eventually, was there a better approach I could have taken, that wouldn't have required me to find a nearly-correct answer first?  And why am I getting all those warning messages before I get the right answer?

Comment: Do you see the exact same messages if you go for higher precision?

Answer (score 5):

The error messages come from `Integrate`/`NIntegrate` calls on functions with symbolic (non-numerical) parameters `a`, `b`, `c`.  These calls come before `FindRoot` substitutes numerical values for these parameters.  (Taking `N` of `Integrate` here is effectively the same as calling `NIntegrate`.)

In this case the best approach it seems to me is to do the integral first, since it can be done.

```
obj = Integrate[
  x^{0, 2, 4} Exp[-(a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c)], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0]
(*
{1/4 Sqrt[b/a] E^(b^2/(8 a) - c) BesselK[1/4, b^2/(8 a)],
 (1/(16 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a^3 b])) *
  E^(b^2/(8 a) - c) π (-b^2 BesselI[-(1/4), b^2/(8 a)] +
   (4 a + b^2) BesselI[1/4, b^2/(8 a)] + 
    b^2 (-BesselI[3/4, b^2/(8 a)] + BesselI[5/4, b^2/(8 a)])),
 (Sqrt[b] E^(b^2/(8 a) - c) ((2 a + b^2) BesselK[1/4, b^2/(8 a)] - 
    b^2 BesselK[3/4, b^2/(8 a)]))/(32 a^(5/2))}
*)

aa = FindRoot[obj - {1, 2, 10}, {a, .01}, {b, .15}, {c, 1.33}]
(*  {a -> 0.0108063, b -> 0.141937, c -> 0.671843}  *)
```

Checks:

```
obj /. aa
(*  {1., 2., 10.}  *)

NIntegrate[x^{0, 2, 4} Exp[-(a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c)] /. aa, {x, 0, Infinity}]
(*  {1., 2., 10.}  *)
```

---

*Further explanation:*

Integrating vector expressions can be tricky.  See [NIntegrate over a list of functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77589/nintegrate-over-a-list-of-functions) and linked questions.

The integration is done on each component separately. `NIntegrate` must see the components in the argument expression.  The following, which is the normal way to use `NumericQ` in numeric solvers like `NIntegrate`, does not work because `NIntegrate` decides the integrand is not a `List` and gets confused when the values are not numbers:

```
i1[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] :=
  (x^{0, 2, 4})*f[x, a, b, c]
FindRoot[NIntegrate[i1[x, a, b, c], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] - {1, 2, 10},
 {a, .01}, {b, .15}, {c, 1.33}]
```

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand i1[x,a,b,c] has evaluated to non-numerical values.... >>

The proper way is to wrap the function up for `FindRoot` instead:

```
obj2[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(x^{0, 2, 4})*f[x, a, b, c], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

But there's still one pitfall. If we substitute this for the integration there's a problem:

```
FindRoot[obj2[a, b, c] - {1, 2, 10}, {a, .01}, {b, .15}, {c, 1.33}]
```

> FindRoot::nveq: The number of equations does not match the number of variables in FindRoot[obj2[a,b,c]-{1,2,10},{a,0.01},{b,0.15},{c,1.33}]. >>

The problem is that the argument to `FindRoot` is evaluated symbolically before `obj2` evaluates.  You get a vector of `obj2` calls:

```
obj2[a, b, c] - {1, 2, 10}
(*  {-1 + obj2[a, b, c], -2 + obj2[a, b, c], -10 + obj2[a, b, c]}  *)
```

When `FindRoot` substitutes values for `a`, `b`, and `c`,  this evaluates and you get a matrix of values.

```
obj2[a, b, c] - {1, 2, 10} /. {a -> 0.01, b -> 0.15, c -> 1.33}
(*
  {{0.0273318, 1.04919, 9.31436},
   {-0.972668, 0.0491918, 8.31436},
   {-8.97267, -7.95081, 0.314357}}
*)
```

The proper way to use `obj2` is to use `==` instead of `-`:

```
FindRoot[obj2[a, b, c] == {1, 2, 10}, {a, .01}, {b, .15}, {c, 1.33}]
(*  {a -> 0.0108063, b -> 0.141937, c -> 1.36499}  *)
```

Comment: The approach you've proposed only works for simple examples that happen to have analytic integrals, but I need to know how to do this for numerical integrals.

Comment: @JerryGuern I think I was typing it up while you made the comment.

Comment: @JerryGuern I'm wondering why you used the symbolic solver `Integrate` instead of the numerical one `NIntegrate`, if you're not interested in symbolic solutions to the integral?  I think that led me to try `Integrate` first. Does the second (numeric) method work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `FindRoot` says

> FindRoot first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates f
>   with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the
>   result numerically.

So the system first evaluates

`Integrate[(x^{0, 2, 4})*f[x, a, b, c], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] - {1, 2, 10} // N`

which gives the errors you see (NIntegrate does the same btw). First we make your problem compatible with this. This mostly means that arguments within these functions should not evaluate to give error messages for non-numerical arguments, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/6804 and http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502 .

This works:

```
ClearAll[g, f, a, b, c];

f[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
  Exp[-(a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c)];
g[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(x^{0, 2, 4})*f[x, a, b, c], {x, -Infinity, 
     Infinity}] - {1, 2, 10};

FindRoot[g[a, b, c], {a, .01}, {b, .15}, {c, 1.33}]
```

as you observed, `FindRoot[g[a, b, c], {a, .1}, {b, .5}, {c, .33}]` doesn't.
The messages states it clearly: `NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand f[x,-3.12487,7.94363,-0.799115] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,17545.1}}. >>`, since `` f[17545.130534855336`, -3.124874458858545`, 7.943629253761611`, -0.7991150536849108`] === Overflow[] ``.

Your exponential becomes gigantic for negative a and large x which can very well occur in the algorithm `FindRoot` uses which can involve evaluating the function anywhere it sees fit. Sometimes it will not be able to find the solution...

Instead of `FindRoot`, let's use `NMinimize` which supports constraints - I'm assuming you only want positive `a` and `b`, so I use `a > 0 && b > 0`. If there is a root, `NMinimize` should find it too. We have to change the problem a bit because `NMinimize` takes a single valued function: apply `Norm`. The `NelderMead` method seems to find the desired solution.

```
NMinimize[{Norm@g[a, b, c], a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, b, c},
 MaxIterations -> 100,
 StepMonitor :> Print[Norm@g[a, b, c], {a, b, c}],
 Method -> "NelderMead"]
(*=>*)
{0.000163492, {a -> 0.0107889, b -> 0.142143, c -> 1.36467}}
```

Hoever note that this kind of global rootfinding/optimization is in general very hard.