# Solving an integral equation for upper boundary

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, integral-equations

I am reading a paper on High Harmonics Generation (HHG) and a Lewenstein model The paper is [here](https://www.osapublishing.org/josab/abstract.cfm?uri=josab-16-4-669). I would like to reproduce some results but I am stuck at the following problem. I have:
$$p(\tau_b,\tau)=\frac{e}{\tau-\tau_b}\int_{\tau_b}^\tau {\rm d}\tau^{'} A(\tau^{'})\,,$$
where $A(\tau)$ is vector potential (given).

The time of birth $t_b$ as a function of $\tau$ is determined by solution of the algebraic equation:
$$p(\tau_b,\tau)-e \, A(\tau_b)=0$$

How should I approach solving such an equation. I was thinking:

```
A[t_] := -Sin[t];
τ = 0.5;
FindRoot[NIntegrate[A[t], {t, τb, τ}]/(τ - τb) - 
A[τb] == 0, {τb, 1}]
```

But Mathematica keeps saying

```
t = τb is not a valid limit of integration
```

Maybe there is an error in my solution. But besides making it work with Mathematica specific approach, what would a more general numerical approach be for such a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: `A[t_] := -Sin[t];
k[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[A[t], {t, s, tau}];
tau = 0.5;
FindRoot[k[tb]/(tau - tb) - A[tb] == 0, {tb, 1}]`

Comment: [This prior thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89797/more-issues-integrate-nintegrate-findroot) might give some indication of why this happens. In short, these are warning messages from attempts at symbolic preprocessing. To avoid that one can do, for example, `In[27]:= rootfunc[\[Tau]b_?NumberQ] := 
 NIntegrate[A[t], {t, \[Tau]b, \[Tau]}]/(\[Tau] - \[Tau]b) - A[\[Tau]b]
FindRoot[rootfunc[\[Tau]b] == 0, {\[Tau]b, 1}]

Out[28]= {\[Tau]b -> 0.5}`

Comment: Properly, if `A` is known this is not an integral equation.

Comment: @george2079 Thank you for clarification. Is there a special name to such a problem if $A$ is known?

Answer (score 2):

"`FindRoot` first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates `f` with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically" is written in the documentation in the [Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html?q=FindRoot) section.

The reason

```
A[t_] := -Sin[t]
τ = 0.5;
FindRoot[NIntegrate[A[t], {t, τb, τ}]/(τ - τb) - A[τb] == 0, {τb, 1}]
```

doesn't work is because it attempts to evaluate

```
NIntegrate[A[t], {t, τb, τ}]
```

symbolically which fails.

Using belisarius's solution

```
k[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[A[t], {t, s, τ}]
FindRoot[k[τb]/(τ - τb) - A[τb] == 0, {τb, 1}]
```

works because `k[τb]` can be evaluated symbolically simply giving back `k[τb]`.

When numerical evaluation is applied the function definition is used enabling

```
NIntegrate[A[t], {t, s, τ}]
```

to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by [Jack LaVigue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10917/jack-lavigne), `FindRoot` by default tries first to evaluate its first argument symbolically, which fails here.  However, it is possible to instruct `FindRoot` not to do so by employing the option `Evaluated -> False`.

```
A[t_] := -Sin[t];
τ = 0.5;
FindRoot[NIntegrate[A[t], {t, τb, τ}]/(τ - τb) - A[τb] == 0, {τb, 1}, Evaluated -> False]
```

`FindRoot` returns without error the not particularly interesting but correct answer `{τb -> 0.5}`.  With an initial guess of `2`, it instead returns `{τb -> 2.0984}`