# Using Associations and Pattern matching in numerical functions possibly broken

Tags: numerics, pattern-matching, associations

It looks like the very young feature of pattern matching (/replacing) within Associations (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119542/6804), with or without `KeyValuePattern`, still has quite some flaws.

Let's define

```
g[KeyValuePattern["x" -> x_?NumericQ]] := x^2;
```

This is ok:

```
g[<|"x" -> x[1]|>]
g[<|"x" -> x[1]|>] /. x[1] -> 0
(*==>*)
g[<|"x" -> x[1]|>]
0
```

But using `g` with Associations in numerical functions does not work:

```
FindMinimum[g@<|"x" -> x[1]|>, {{x[1], 0}}]
NIntegrate[g@<|"x" -> x[1]|>, {x[1], 0, 1}]
(*==>*)
FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value g[<|x->x[1]|>] is not a real number at {x[1]} = {0.}. >>
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand g[<|x->x[1]|>] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. >>
```

Using Lists of rules, whether right away or via `Normal` works:

```
NIntegrate[g@Normal@<|"x" -> x[1]|>, {x[1], 0, 1}]
NIntegrate[g@{"x" -> x[1]}, {x[1], 0, 1}]
FindMinimum[g@{"x" -> x[1]}, {{x[1], 0}}]
FindMinimum[g@Normal@<|"x" -> x[1]|>, {{x[1], 0}}]
(*==>*)
0.333333
{0., {x[1] -> 0.}}
```

Am I missing something obvious or can this be considered a bug?

These things are quite important to have fixed if we want to use `Associations` for some object-oriented programming...

---

**Edit**

Thanks to Alexey Popkov I now know that everything I described here behaves as is to be expected. Since `Association` has `HoldAllComplete`, the expression `g[<|"x" -> x[1]|>]`, created when `x[1]` is undefined, will always stay `g[<|"x" -> x[1]|>]`, even when `x[1]` is assigned some value later.

I find this a bit confusing, `Associations` really don't behave like a *markup-style* `Head` that you might define yourself:

A plain

`person["age" -> x, "height" -> 2]`

does in general not behave like

`Association["age" -> x, "size" -> 2]`

You might even argue that the first variant is more readable for object-oriented programming, because the head gives information about the type of object.

Comment: It is not a bug (imo), take a look at this answer [More issues Integrate, NIntegrate, FindRoot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89803/5478) and a generic topic: [User-defined functions \[...\] and NumericQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/5478). I don't know how to correct your approach easily `_?NumericQ` isn't the answer here. The only way (i see) is to put to `NIntegrate` what you want to integrate, don't use fancy syntax/evaluation features there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update

The original answer gives consistent explanation of this behavior as being a consequence of the `HoldAllComplete` attribute of `Association`. But before *Mathematica* 10.4 `Association` [didn't have this attribute](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124603/280) but evaluated in the same way. Here are outputs from version 10.0.1:

```
Association // Attributes
```

> ```
> {Protected}
> ```

```
Association[x + x -> 1 + 1]
```

> ```
> <|2 x -> 2|>
> ```

```
assoc = Association["x" -> y]
```

> ```
> <|"x" -> y|>
> ```

```
y = 1; assoc
```

> ```
> <|"x" -> y|>
> ```

This means that my original explanation is only superficially correct and the observed behavior comes not from the `HoldAllComplete` attribute of `Association` but from the fact that after the **first** evaluation of the syntactic construct "`Association[...]`" (where `Association` is indeed just an ordinary head like `List` or `Hold`) we get [entirely different object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54493/280) whose behavior can't be explained simply considering attributes and which isn't like a usual container like `List` or `Hold`. But the behavior of this object upon evaluation in the *standard* situations is as if it would be a usual container like `HoldComplete`.

---

#### Original answer

What happens here is that `Association` has attribute `HoldAllComplete` and hence does not evaluate `x[1]` to a numerical value:

```
Clear[x];
assoc = <|"x" -> x[1]|>;
x[1] = 0;
assoc
```

> ```
> <|"x" -> x[1]|>
> ```

Numerical functions work by assigning values to the variables and then evaluating the objective function, they don't perform replacement like in your example

```
g[<|"x" -> x[1]|>] /. x[1] -> 0
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

This is the reason why your approach fails, no bugs here.

Comment: Oh, right, all of these functions localize variables effectively using Block, so in a sense they overwrite global variables during each evaluation and then reset them again.

Comment: Just curious: Can you maybe elaborate on what you can read from the error message other than that Experimental'NumericalFunction is involved, and that the expression is converted to it before stuff starts failing.

Comment: I'm not sure whether your 'Further elaboration' really shows an additional problem. In line with what you said, Association has HoldAllComplete, so `g[<|"x" -> x|>]` will, after having been evaluated once, never evaluate to `g[<|"x" -> 0|>]`, even when you assign 0 to x later on. I think the only real problem is in the inconsistency of Plot and NIntegrate et. al then?

Comment: @masterxilo It seems I was wrong saying that `g[a_Association] /; NumericQ[a["x"]] := a["x"]^2;` should work. But the problem is subtle: once evaluated `assoc = <|"x" -> x|>` will never become `<|"x" -> 0|>` BUT `assoc["x"]` will return `0` if `x = 0`. With my definition I tried to use this feature. Now I see that if the RHS of the expression `y = g[<|"x" -> x|>]` is evaluated once to `g[<|"x" -> x|>]`, then `x = 0; y` will return `g[<|"x" -> x|>]` with my definition.

Comment: @masterxilo It is indeed related to the `HoldAllComplete` attribute and works the same way if we use `HoldComplete` instead of `Association`. Try the definition `h[HoldComplete[x_]] /; NumericQ[x] := x^2`: evaluation of `x =.; y = h[HoldComplete[x]]; x = 0; y` returns `h[HoldComplete[x]]`. But if we replace `HoldComplete` with `Hold`, it returns `0`. So I was wrong, I'll remove the corresponding part of my answer (but it will be kept in the edit history if one is interested).

Comment: The only thing that puzzles me is why `Plot[g[<|"x" -> x|>], {x, 0, 1}]` works with my definition for `g`. Even `Plot[Evaluate@g[<|"x" -> x|>], {x, 0, 1}]` works...

Comment: I'm confused about the `HoldAllComplete` attribute, if one evaluates `x[1]=0; <|"x" -> x[1]|>`, it will return  `<|"x" -> 0|>`, however, as you've shown, assign a name (`assoc`) to `Association` and evaluate `assoc` again will somehow prevent it from further evaluation (to 0). Why would this happen? IMHO, the `HoldAllComplete` should even prevent `<|"x"->1+1|>` from being `<|"x"->2|>`.

Comment: @luyuwuli You can ask a separate question on why it is implemented in this way (if there is no one already) but in a comment I can only say that the `HoldAllComplete` attribute prevents evaluation of arguments **inside of the head** which has this attribute and no more. For example: `SetAttributes[f, HoldAllComplete]; f[arg_] := g[arg]; f[1 + 1]` returns `g[2]` as expected. In the case of `Association` after evaluation you get [entirely different object](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54493/280) which isn't like `HoldComplete[...]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for your reply. My confusion is, by internal definitions of `Association`, one can evaluate the "held part", however, compare `x[1]=0; <|"x" -> x[1]|>`(it returns `<|"x" -> 0|>`) with the example in your post (it only assign a name to it, and it returns `<|"x" -> x[1]|>`) How could be this possible? What prevents it from further evaluation (to `<|"x" -> 0|>`)?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for your links in the comment. Even though I've seen it long time ago, I'm still now struggling to understand the long post written by Leonid.

Comment: @luyuwuli It is possible (in part) to achieve this using the [Villegas-Gayley technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/590388) but in the case of `Associations` we probably have something deeply wired into the system. Actually `Association` [originally didn't have the `HoldAllComplete` attribute at all](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124603/280), so strictly speaking the explanation provided in my answer may be only superficially correct. Unfortunately I can't provide better explanation, and I think that it is worth to ask specific question on this issue.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your explanation. I'll post a new question related to this:)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I thought  Villegas-Gayley technique for a while but still can't find the solution to the question. I've post a new [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126033/6468) related to this. Wish you could help me.