# Association's Attributes change between 10.3.1 & 10.4?

Tags: evaluation, associations, language-design

In Mathematica 10.3.1

```
In[1]:= Attributes[Association]
Out[1]= {Protected}
```

In Mathematica 10.4:

```
In[1]:= Attributes[Association]
Out[1]= {HoldAllComplete,Protected}
```

I am just curious in regards to the reason behind this change. What is the advantage? Is it a documented change?

Comment: In addition to the documentation that you show, i.e., `Attributes[Association]`, this is also documented by `Information[Association]` (`??Association`) or `Definition[Association]`. The documentation page for `Association` states that it was `Updated in 2016 (10.4)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One significant difference is the following

In version 10.3.1

```
a = 3;
Association[Unevaluated[a -> 2]][Unevaluated[a]]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

In version 11.0.1

```
a = 3;
Association[Unevaluated[a -> 2]][Unevaluated[a]]
```

> ```
> Association[Unevaluated[a->2]][Unevaluated[a]]
> ```

In version 11.0.1 (clearing attributes)

```
Unprotect[Association];
ClearAttributes[Association, HoldAllComplete];
a = 3;
Association[Unevaluated[a -> 2]][Unevaluated[a]]
SetAttributes[Association, HoldAllComplete];
```

> ```
> Missing[KeyAbsent,3] 
> (*should be interpreted as Missing[KeyAbsent, a], as 3 is actually a valid key here*)
> ```

I see this change as a reminder that that `Association` is not meant to be used like this (with keys that are "unstable"/unevaluated). In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60538/4330), taliesin says: "But generally this just sounds like a dangerous and confusing game to play, to me". There have been good arguments against using `Association` like this, like the fact that if you `Compress` and `Uncompress` an `Association`, it would evaluate its keys.

Interestingly it is still possible to create a broken association in 11.0.1, which may be a bug of `PositionIndex`.

```
a = "Fail!";
p = PositionIndex[Unevaluated[{a, b, c, d}]]
Uncompress@Compress@p
```

> ```
> <|a->{1},b->{2},c->{3},d->{4}|>
> <|Fail!->{1},b->{2},c->{3},d->{4}|>
> ```

An aspect of the difference is that in versions newer than 10.4, evaluation takes place "behind the scenes". This explains the shorter traces in mikado's answer.

In version 10.3.1

```
Trace[Association[1 + 1 -> 2]]
```

> ```
> {{{1+1,2},2->2,2->2},Association[2->2],<|2->2|>}
> ```

In version 11.0.1

```
Trace[Association[1 + 1 -> 2]]
Trace[Association[1 + 1 -> 2], TraceInternal -> True]
```

> ```
> {Association[1+1->2],<|2->2|>}
> {Association[1+1->2],{{{1+1,2},2->2,2->2},{2->2}},<|2->2|>}
> ```

Comment: And not just compress/uncompress, but serialize in any possible way, except writing to an `.mx` file: that includes at least converting to string (`Save`) or boxes, or sending through MathLink (parallelization!!), writing to WDX, in addition to Compress.  I.e. this is a very common thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

We can investigate the difference in behaviours using `ClearAttributes` and `SetAttributes`.  One apparently minor benefit of setting `HoldAllComplete` is simpler `Trace` expressions.

```
ClearAttributes[Association, HoldAllComplete];
Trace[Association[a -> 1, b -> 2]] // Length
(* 4 *)

SetAttributes[Association, HoldAllComplete];
Trace[Association[a -> 1, b -> 2]] // Length
(* 2 *)
```

I've not been able to construct any other examples where the difference is significant, but maybe someone else can spot something.

*EDIT*

Despite further investigation, I cannot find any cases where changing the attributes of `Association` make a significant difference, so I enter into speculation on the reason for the change.  Here are some possibilities:

1. There is a subtle bug introduced by not having the `HoldAllComplete` attribute that was only discovered after the release of 10.3.1.
2. There is some performance impact of not having the attribute e.g. additional checks that need to be made for some unlikely case.
3. There is some planned new functionality that would require this attribute.
4. `Association` has always behaved as if it had `HoldAllComplete` (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119607/36788).  It is easier for users to understand and reason about if this is made explicit.

I tend to favour this final explanation.

Comment: Maybe the key is that [pattern matching with associations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125377/what-changes-were-made-to-core-functions-during-the-10-x-series/125378?noredirect=1#comment340382_125378) was added at the same time.

Comment: Mikado, I felt my answer here might interest you.