# Sequence in Association

Tags: evaluation

Inspired by this question [Association's Attributes change between 10.3.1 & 10.4?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124603/36788) I have been feeding a variety of strange expressions into `Association`.

*WARNING MAY CAUSE KERNEL CRASH*

```
Association[a -> Sequence[]]
(* <|a -> Sequence[]|> *)
```

Completes OK

```
Association[a -> Sequence[b]]
(* <|a -> Sequence[b]|> *)
```

Completes OK

```
Association[a -> Sequence[b, c]]
(* <|a -> Sequence[b, c]|> *)
```

Hangs until aborted or apparently completes but kills kernel

```
Association[a -> Sequence[b, c, d]]
(* <|a -> Sequence[b, c, d]|> *)
```

Apparently completes but kills kernel

```
$Version
(* "11.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)" *)
```

Or with similar results

```
$Version
(* "10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)" *)
```

Do other people see this?

Comment: Nope, no crash or hang on OS X M11.0.0.  But that doesn't mean that there's no bug. Crash bugs have the nasty habit of not always triggering ... or sometimes causing very subtle problems.

Comment: confirmed on 10.1/windows

Comment: No problem either for me with OSX and mma 11.0.0.

Comment: No problem from 10.2 to 11.0 on Windows.

Comment: No problem on widnows: "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2016)"