# How to use ReplaceAll and RuleDelayed with an Association?

Tags: evaluation, replacement, associations, rule

I expected that something like this

```
assoc = <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> <|"a" -> "str2", "b" -> <||>|>|>;
assoc /. <|"a" -> v_, "b" -> <||>|> :> v <> "0"
```

would evaluate to

> ```
> <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str20"|>
> ```

Obviously, it doesn't.

Instead, the result is

> ```
> <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str2" <> "0"|>
> ```

which can turn into the desired output *if it is evaluated* eg manually.

I've also tried using `KeyValuePattern` but the result is the same.

`assoc` is deceivingly simple in structure because I made it so for clarity of exposition. My actual problem entails deeper associations eg

```
<|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> <|
  "c1" -> 1, "c2" -> 2, "c3" -> <|
    "a" -> "str2", "b" -> <|
      "c4" -> <|"a" -> "str3", "b" -> <||>|>, "c5" -> 3
     |>
    |>
   |>
  |>
```

My question is, how to achieve the desired output using rules or if that's not possible what other recourse is there available?

Comment: Try `Replace[<|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> <|"a" -> "str2", "b" -> <||>|>|>, KeyValuePattern[{"a" -> x_, "b" -> <||>}] :> x <> "0", {1}]`.

Comment: @J.M. _This_ is certainly worth an answer. You should also mention that the introduction of `KeyValuePattern` is necessary because `Association`s are atomic.

Comment: Use `RuleCondition`: `assoc /. <|"a" -> v_, "b" -> <||>|> :> RuleCondition [v <> "0"]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin What is `RuleCondition`? When I look it up in the help documentation it is not found.

Comment: @JackLaVigne *"When I look it up in the help documentation it is not found"* - that's right. And it won't ever be, I think. But, [plenty of it on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=RuleCondition), particularly [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replacement-inside-held-expression/29319#29319). Also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128453/pattern-matching-to-a-function-evaluation-inside-an-association/128456#128456) may be of interest.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Actually, the last link I gave, is an exact same question, so voting to close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  The link you gave explains that `Association` is `HoldAllComplete` which necessitates the use of `RuleCondition`. Why then does `Replace` work?

Comment: @JackLaVigne In fact, `Replace` working here looks like a bug. I will report it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment rather than an answer. Using this definition:

```
assoc = <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> <|"a" -> "str2", "b" -> <||>|>|>
(* <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> <|"a" -> "str2", "b" -> <||>|>|> *)
```

when applying this replacement the result was:

```
assoc /. <|"a" -> v_, "b" -> <||>|> :> v <> "0"
(* <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str2" <> "0"|> *)
```

whereas the expected result was:

```
(* <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str20"|> *)
```

### JM suggested using Replace with KeyValuePattern

Using `Replace` with `KeyValuePattern` produces the desired result:

```
Replace[assoc, KeyValuePattern[{"a" -> v_, "b" -> <||>}] :> v <> "0", {1}]
(* <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str20"|> *)
```

### Result is not related to KeyValuePattern

I discovered that `KeyValuePattern` is not the cure, rather it was using `Replace` rather than `ReplaceAll`.

Observe the results below.

```
Replace[assoc, <|"a" -> v_, "b" -> <||>|> :> v <> "0", {1}]
(* <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str20"|> *)

ReplaceAll[assoc, <|"a" -> v_, "b" -> <||>|> :> v <> "0"]
(* <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str2" <> "0"|> *)

ReplaceAll[assoc,KeyValuePattern[{"a" -> v_, "b" -> <||>}] :> v <> "0"]
(* <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str2" <> "0"|> *)
```

Independent of the whether we use `KeyValuePattern` or not, `Replace` appears to evaluate the result whereas `ReplaceAll` returns the result without evaluation.

### Using List rather than Association

If rather than using an association we use a list, the problem disappears.

```
listOfRules = {{"a" -> "str1"}, {"b" -> {"a" -> "str2"}}}
(* {{"a" -> "str1"}, {"b" -> {"a" -> "str2"}}} *)

Replace[listOfRules, {"a" -> v_, "b" -> {}} :> v <> "0", Infinity]
(* {"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str20"} *)

ReplaceAll[listOfRules, {"a" -> v_, "b" -> {}} :> v <> "0"]
(* {"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str20"} *)
```

### Particular solution

It is interesting than to see that for this particular problem one could convert the association to a list, make the replacement and then convert it back to an association.

```
assoc /. Association -> List /. {"a" -> v_, "b" -> {}} :> v <> "0" // Association
(* <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str20"|> *)
```

I don't recommend this (I think J.M's suggestion is the way to go).

### Conclusion

It appears that applying `ReplaceAll` to an association returns the result without evaluation whereas `Relace` evaluates the result.

This observation is unrelated to the use of `KeyValuePattern`.

Comment: Looks like I don't need to write an answer anymore... :D

Comment: @J.M. Could you explain why `Replace` evaluates the result while `ReplaceAll` does not? Is this expected?

Comment: @Alexey, I actually don't know, which makes Leonid's technique in the comments even more mystifying.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe J.M. doesn't need to write an answer anymore, but I think this answer based on [Leonid Shifrin's earlier answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128456/3066) should be recorded.

```
assoc = <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> <|"a" -> "str2", "b" -> <||>|>|>;
assoc /. <|"a" -> v_, "b" -> <||>|> :> RuleCondition[v <> "0"]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> "str1", "b" -> "str20"|>
> ```