# How can I create an atomic head or treat some head as atomic during Map?

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, map, undocumented, head

For example,

```
Map[g, {0, {h[1, 2, 3]}}, {-1}]
```

gives

```
{g[0], {h[g[1], g[2], g[3]]}}
```

I want a `atomicHead` that can prevent deeper inspection of its sub parts, so that

```
Map[g, {0, {atomicHead[1, 2, 3]}}, {-1}]
```

gives

```
{g[0], {g[atomicHead[1, 2, 3]]}}
```

Is it possible to have such an `atomicHead`? Or even better, to make Head `h` seem atomic to `Map` function.

Comment: Use `Compress`? :D

Comment: @xzczd How to use `Compress` in this case? Actually, if I have an `atomicHead`. What I want to do is temporarily replace some Head with `atomicHead`, and do `Map`, finally replace the Heads back.

Comment: Hmm… Then `Compress` doesn't help. What's in my mind is something like `Map[g, {0, {Compress@atomicHead[1, 2, 3]}}, {-1}] /. str_String :> Uncompress@str` As you can see, it's not even comparable with Alexey Popkov's solution below.

Comment: @xzczd I think your `Compress` solution can be improved as an alternative solution. I found `Compress` always returns string begin with "1:eJ"(though I not that sure, because the documentation does not say this) which is very special. So we can do this `Map[g, {0, {h[1, 2, 3]}} /. h -> Compress@*h, {-1}] /. 
 str_String?(StringMatchQ["1:eJ" ~~ __]) :> Uncompress[str]`. It is not as 100 percent robust as Popkov's solution, but I think it also very good as long as you do not really have "1:eJ" string as normal data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139974/280) tutorial,

```
tmp = atomicHead[1, 2, 3];
System`Private`SetNoEntry@tmp
Map[g, {0, {tmp}}, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {g[0], {g[atomicHead[1, 2, 3]]}}
> ```

---

**Update in response to comments**

Alternatively, you can automatically make expressions atomic based on their `Head`s:

```
expr = {0, {atomicHead[1, 2, 3], {atomicHead[1, 2, 3, 4]}}};
Map[g, expr /. 
  atomicHead[args___] :> System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[atomicHead, args], {-1}]
```

> ```
> {g[0], {g[atomicHead[1, 2, 3]], {g[atomicHead[1, 2, 3, 4]]}}}
> ```

---

**Update 2**

I just realized that I overlooked the simplest and most direct solution:

```
expr = {0, {atomicHead[1, 2, 3], {atomicHead[1, 2, 3, 4]}}};
Map[g, expr /. a_atomicHead :> System`Private`SetNoEntry[a], {-1}]
```

> ```
> {g[0], {g[atomicHead[1, 2, 3]], {g[atomicHead[1, 2, 3, 4]]}}}
> ```

Comment: Hi, Alexey Popkov, Thank you for answering. I found this solution before. But I do not want change whole expression to a tmp, then make it atomic. As I replied to xzczd, I want to do Head replacement

Comment: @matheorem I updated the answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Oh, Yeah! That is great. Thank you very much for your clever solution : )

Comment: One more thing. Why can not this `atomicHead`  be replaced directly? I mean `Map[g, expr /. 
  atomicHead[args___] :> System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[atomicHead, args], {-1}]/.atomicHead->anyOtherHead`

Comment: @matheorem Because it is already atomic. :) You can do as follows: ``Map[g, expr /. 
   atomicHead[args___] :> System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[atomicHead, args], {-1}] /. 
 x_ /; Head[x] === atomicHead :> Replace[x, h_[args___] :> anyOtherHead[args]]``. But you don't need this backward replacement step because you can make your original head `h` atomic inside of your expresion without replacing it with `atomicHead`.

Comment: the last sentence is a good point : )

Comment: @matheorem I updated the answer with an even simpler (and probably more efficient) solution. :^)

Comment: After I discover the recursion problem in `Quantity`, I also get this simpler solution, SetNoEntry seems to be more robust : ).   What Annoying me now is that `expr = {0, {Quantity[1, "kg"]}};
Map[g, <|1 -> expr|> /. 
  a_atomicHead :> System`Private`SetNoEntry[a], {-1}]` does not work.

Comment: @matheorem [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128456/280) is a solution: ``expr={0,{Quantity[1,"kg"]}};Map[g,<|1->expr|>/.    a_Quantity:>RuleCondition@System`Private`SetNoEntry[a],{-1}]``.

Comment: Finally the perfect solution for every case as far as I know. You saved my day:) Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**

`` System`Private`ConstructNoEntry `` will enter recursion in some cases, See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/269981/4742). `` System`Private`SetNoEntry `` is more robust and simple.

Also `Association` is a special construct, normal replacement does not work for it. **Alexey Popkov provides a perfect workaround in his comments. All credits to Alexey Popkov**.

I just organize some examples for quick reference

Below is the final form of `makeAtomic`

```
makeAtomic[head_] := 
 a_head :> RuleCondition@System`Private`SetNoEntry[a]
```

Now, no matter List or Association expression both works

```
expr = {0, Quantity[1, "kg"]};
Map[g, expr /. makeAtomic[Quantity], {-1}]
Map[g, <|1 -> expr|> /. makeAtomic[Quantity], {-1}]
```

gives

```
{g[0], g[Quantity[1, "Kilograms"]]}
<|1 -> {g[0], g[Quantity[1, "Kilograms"]]}|>
```

---

**Previous:**

Completely inspired by Alexey Popkov. I just make a simpler interface.

We could define

```
makeAtomic[head_] := 
 HoldPattern[head[args___]] :> 
  System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[head, args]
```

Now define

```
expr = {0, Quantity[1, "kg"], BesselJ[3, x]};
```

then

```
Map[g, expr, {-1}]
```

gives

```
{g[0], Quantity[g[1], g["Kilograms"]], BesselJ[g[3], g[x]]}
```

and

```
Map[g, expr /. {makeAtomic[Quantity], makeAtomic[BesselJ]}, {-1}]
```

gives

```
{g[0], g[Quantity[1, "Kilograms"]], g[BesselJ[3, x]]}
```

---

What is more, we can really make an atomic Head like

```
atomicHead[x___] := System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[atomicHeadCore, x]
```

then

```
Map[g, {0, atomicHead[1, 2, 3]}, {-1}]
```

gives

```
{g[0], g[atomicHeadCore[1, 2, 3]]}
```

Note the Head is `atomicHeadCore` not `atomicHead`.
If you want to change to some other Head, you can do

```
Map[g, {0, atomicHead[1, 2, 3]}, {-1}] /. 
 atomicHeadCore[x___] :> anyOtherHead[x]
```

which gives

```
{g[0], g[anyOtherHead[1, 2, 3]]}
```