# Why does System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[Quantity, 1, "kg"] enter a Recursion?

Tags: recursion, undocumented, units

```
System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[BesselJ, 0, x]
```

works fine, and outputs

```
BesselJ[0, x]
```

However,

```
System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[Quantity, 1, "kg"]
```

enters a recursion and outputs

[image: $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of QuantityUnitsPrivateiu:IndependentUnit[_String].]

Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because `KnownUnitQ["kg"]` returns `False`, and hence `Quantity` tries to resolve `"kg"` to `"Kilograms"`. To avoid this, use only known units in the input:

```
System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[Quantity, 1, "Kilograms"]
```

To get the right form for the input of `Quantity`, apply `InputForm`:

```
Quantity[1, "kg"] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Quantity[1, "Kilograms"]
> ```

---

Alternatively, just apply `` System`Private`SetNoEntry `` *after* evaluation of `Quantity[1, "kg"]`:

```
System`Private`SetNoEntry[Quantity[1, "kg"]]
```

Comment: That is interesting. But I do not see why Quantity tries to resolve "kg" to "Kilograms" will enter a recursion.

Comment: @matheorem You can `Trace` what actually happens. Usage of ``System`Private`ConstructNoEntry`` is a kind of a hack which allows to construct an atomic object representing an expression which normally shouldn't be atomic. This breaks things like part extraction, applying replacement rules via `ReplaceAll`, etc. (which can be used by `Quantity` internally).

Answer (score 5):

"Why does `` System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[Quantity, 1, "kg"] `` enter a Recursion"?  Because the developers of the `Quantity` function have every expectation that a `Quantity` object will not be atomic, and write the code accordingly. This is a reasonable assumption for them to make.

Seems like a case of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Comment: Hi, Jason B. Thank you for answering. But `BesselJ[0, x]` is also not atomic, why doesn't it suffer recursion problem?

Comment: @matheorem - I responded a couple times and deleted the response, will try again. Whether `BesselJ` gives a recursion error when used incorrectly is not an interesting question.  My point was that if you do ridiculous things like in the OP here, don't be surprised when things blow up in your face.  Try `Block[{Quiet=Quit}, Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}]]` if you want more examples of garbage-in garbage-out

Comment: Hi, Jason B. Thank you very much for comment : ) I understand your point. But I do not think ``System`Private`ConstructNoEntry[Quantity, 1, "kg"]`` is ridiculous thing. As far as I know, ``System`Private`ConstructNoEntry`` is used for making any Head atomic, why not `Quantity`. Anyway, as point out by Alexey Popkov, ``System`Private`SetNoEntry`` works for `Quantity`, so I would think there is some buggy things in ``System`Private`ConstructNoEntry`` that make it fail for `Quantity`. Finally, since these are undocumented functions, I agree it may not be a great deal :)