# How to force evaluation of RuleDelayed?

Tags: evaluation, associations

(I'm not sure if the title of this question is appropriate, sorry!)

After defining selfApply function that resolves the mutual references contained in Association, I wrote the following code:

```
selfApply[x_Association] := x //. x;

u[a_] := Module[{f},
  f[t_] := t^2; (*f is actually intended to be non-Listable function *)
  
  selfApply@<|"x" -> 2 a, "y" -> (f /@ "x"), "z" -> "y"[[2]]|>
  ]
u[Range[3]]
```

The result I expect is
`<|"x" -> {2, 4, 6}, "y" -> {4, 16, 36}, "z" -> 16|>`, but the output is

```
Part::partd: Part specification y[[2]] is longer than depth of object.
<|"x" -> {2, 4, 6}, "y" -> {2, 4, 6}, "z" -> 4|>
```

with warning.

It is obvious that it stucks at the stage of evaluating `f /@ "x"` and `"y"[[2]]`, so I tried to rewrite it as follows using RuleDelayed:

```
selfApply[x_Association] := x //. x;

u[a_] := Module[{f},
  f[t_] := t^2;
  
  selfApply@<|"x" -> 2 a, "y" :> f /@ "x", "z" :> "y"[[2]]|>
  ]
v = u[Range[3]]
v["y"]
v["z"]
```

and got outputs:

```
<|"x" -> {2, 4, 6}, "y" :> f$729435 /@ {2, 4, 6},"z" :> (f$729435 /@ {2, 4, 6})[[2]]|>
{4, 16, 36}
16
```

The results of `v["y"]`,`v["z"]` are just what I want, but this behavior is uncomfortable in the following ways:

1. It appears that `f` is not evaluated when the result is assigned to `v`, but is evaluated when specifically calling `v["y"]`.
   Because of this, calculation results are unsure just by calling `v`.
   Also, if the processing of `f` is complicated, there is a concern that performance will be affected because `f` will run every time an element of `v` is accessed.
2. The scope of `f` defined in `Module` is leaking, and the definitions multiply with each execution.
   Example:

```s
s; s; s;
Names["Global`f$*"]
```

and output:

```
{"f$", "f$9454", "f$9455", "f$9456"}
```

The definitions of the form `f$*` increases each time `s` is executed.

---

My naive idea of using Evaluate also didn't work:`Evaluate /@ u[Range[3]]` or `AssociationMap[Evaluate, u[Range[3]]]`.

I feel like my idea of ​​using RuleDelayed is possibly fundamentally wrong...
Is there any elegant solution?

Comment: If you insist on `selfApply` (which I don't understand the motivation), `//AssociationThread[Keys[#],Values[#]]&` can evaluate the delayed values.

Comment: The scope of `f` is not leaking - it's the designed behaviour. Every time `Module` is evaluated, the local vars will be generated to ensure the uniqueness. Why enclose `f`? You can simply hide it in some other context.

Comment: I often use the strategy of selfApply when solving physical systems with a large number of parameters and their relationships mixed together. For example: ```selfApply@<|diam -> 1., dens -> 3., vel -> 2., area -> Pi (diam/2)^2, 
  flux -> dens*vel*area|>``` , while I'm not sure if this way is common.

Comment: Using AssociationThread looked trivial at first, but it seems to meet my needs successfully. Thank you!

Comment: And yes, I know that local variables in a ```Module``` will be added to the global context. No matter how many times I run ```Module[{x}, x = 1]; Names["x*"]```, the result will be {x}, while the example I presented will multiply variables of the form ```f$*``` in the context each time it is run. This is what I'm concerned about since it can be interpreted as a kind of memory leak.

Comment: The code may be somewhat unnatural as a result of simplifying to ask the question. A bit more realistic code: ```f[x_, a_] := Exp[a x]; u[a_] := Module[{s}, s = Mean[a]; selfApply@<|"x" -> a, "y" :> (f[#, s] & /@ "x"), "z" :> "y"[[2]]|>  ]; u[Range[3]]```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I also don't know if there is a standard way of constructing associations that depend on itself. see e.g. the discussions here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/278535/86893. Currently I use the most trivial method like `Module[{vars},vars=...,<|keys->vars|>]`.

Comment: For the "leaking" of local variables, I believe it's due to nested scopings of `Module` and `SetDelayed` although I didn't test, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119403/ and related questions therein. I mean it's somewhat a common phenomenon but not well-documented.

Answer (score 2):

Besides reconstruct the association via e.g. `AssociationThread`, you can also use the trick of in-place evaluation:

```
selfApply[x_Association] := x //. x;

u[a_] := Module[{f},
  f[t_] := t^2;
  <|"x" -> 2 a, "y" :> f /@ "x", "z" :> "y"[[2]]|>//selfApply//Replace[#,x_:>RuleCondition@x,{1}]&
  ]
v = u[Range[3]]

(*<|"x" -> {2, 4, 6}, "y" :> {4, 16, 36}, "z" :> 16|>*)
```

see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128456/86893. The undocumented `RuleCondition` (but quite stable across different versions) can also be replaced by documented functions, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29318/86893