# Simplifying the values in an association

Tags: simplifying-expressions, associations

How can I simplify the expressions of the values in an association in a simple way?

For example,

```
as = <|c1 -> x, c2 -> y x + y x + x x + y y , c3 -> z|> ;

as// Simplify
```

does not give the result

> `<|c1 -> x, c2 -> (x + y)^2, c3 -> z|>`

in Ver 11.0.

Comment: `AssociationThread[Keys[as], Simplify[Values[as]]]`, among others...

Comment: In version 10.1 `Simplify /@ as` returns `<|c1 -> x, c2 -> (x + y)^2, c3 -> z|>` -- what do you get?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - beat me to it, you sly fox. Same in 10.3

Comment: @ciao I am wondering how http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124603/121 affects this, or if it does at all.

Answer (score 2):

`Simplify` threads over lists, but not over associations, so

```
as // Normal // Simplify
```

> `{c1 -> x, c2 -> (x + y)^2, c3 -> z}`

works, but

```
as // Simplify
```

doesn't. Recommend using `Map`

```
Simplify /@ as
```

> `Association[c1 -> x, c2 -> (x + y)^2, c3 -> z]`

as suggested in the comments to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
AssociationMap[Simplify][as]
```

> `<|c1 -> x, c2 -> (x + y)^2, c3 -> z|>`