# Relation between the syntactic and evaluated Association

Tags: evaluation, core-language, associations, language-design

This question is inspired by this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119607/6468) and related to unsolved post "[`Association`'s `Attributes` change between 10.3.1 & 10.4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124603/6468)".

Consider the case of pre-evaluated `Association`:

```
Clear[y];
assoc = <|"x" -> y|>;
y = 0;
assoc
```

> ```
> <|"x" -> y|>
> ```

However with the above definition for `y` we get for a new `Association`:

```
<|"x" -> y|>
```

> ```
> <|"x" -> 0|>
> ```

The first question: **what prevents `assoc` from being further evaluated to `<|"x" -> 0|>` and why the new `Association` doesn't hold its arguments?**

The second question is related to the structure of `Association`. Let us compare evaluated and unevaluated `Association`:

```
AtomQ@<|"x" -> y|>
AtomQ@Unevaluated@<|"x" -> y|>
```

> ```
> True
>
> False
> ```

```
Depth[<|"x" -> y|>]
Depth[Unevaluated@<|"x" -> y|>]
```

> ```
> 2
>
> 3
> ```

Despite the above `TreeForm` in the both cases shows that we have atomic objects:

```
TreeForm[<|"x" -> y|>]
TreeForm[Unevaluated@<|"x" -> y|>]
```

> [image: treeform]
>
> [image: treeform]

So, is `Association` atomic or not? How to understand this controversy?
Is there a special internal definition for `Association` causing this behavior?

Comment: Of interest, this [comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55526/matchq-ing-associations-mma-10/109383#comment159573_55529).

Comment: Regarding the `AtomQ` part of question I do not see a difference to say `Graph`. Unless with raw objects like stings or numbers, the head must be evaluated so that the atomic quality is recognized, mustn't it? For example, a Graph-object with a false body will not be an atom...

Comment: Note, that `TreeForm[Plus[1, Unevaluated@Association["x" -> y]]]` willl not show an atomic structure. This is very depending on the evaluation process...

Comment: These are two very interesting questions and I think they would be better answered if posed separately. Hence my close vote.

Comment: Isn't this because `Association` is both a constructor and a container? For example, `Hold[<|1 -> 1|>] === With[{x = <|1 -> 1|>}, Hold[x]]` evaluates to `False`, indicating that there is some construction step going on that makes a constructed association different from the raw input.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I'd upvote that answer.