# Mathematica 10.2 is slow to NIntegrate highly oscillatory integrals

Tags: numerical-integration, system-performance, backslide, version-10.2

I noticed that *Mathematica* V10.2 is taking much longer to run my code when compared with V9. One function that seems affected is `NIntegrate`. For example, for a highly oscillatory integrand like

```
f = Interpolation[Table[{x, Cos[x 100]}, {x, 0, π, 10^-6}]]
```

evaluating the numerical integration

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 30 π/400}, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]//AbsoluteTiming
```

took 0.00286sec (on V9) and 0.48sec (on V10.2) -- a factor of 160.

Would you know why *Mathematica* 10.2 is taking so much longer to calculate some functions?

Comment: Hi there:) I edited your question for you and added code formatting. To learn how to properly format your question yourself please have a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: NIntegrate isn't every supposed to be ran on an Interpolation. So they probably didn't care too much about making sure it runs fast. 
They've upgraded a lot of things with Interpolation since version 9. Perhaps version 9 had a special shortcut it used directly on the InterpolationObject instead of calling it like a numerical function? Who knows.

Comment: Actually, judging from the results, it's probably the opposite. I bet version 10 tries to do something smart behind the scenes with the Interpolation instead of treating it as a function.

Comment: That was my first guess, but the rule "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0 should avoid MM of doing smart things when performing numerical calculations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having put in some time trying to see what's going, I've found a few things, but I don't have a perfectly clear picture.  I believe **the issue is with the large `InterpolatingFunction` in the integrand and not with `NIntegrate` per se.**
The time it takes for `NIntegrate` to set up the integration is much longer in V10, but the integration itself runs in about the same amount of time in V10 as in V9.  One can get around the issue with [`?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).

What is unclear still is how the size of the `InterpolatingFunction` comes to be an issue inside `NIntegrate`.  Is it something that `NIntegrate` does? Or is it something *Mathematica* does that is outside the control of `NIntegrate`?  Why in V10 but not in V9?  I can't be sure.  I suspect it is outside `NIntegrate`'s control.  It's probably worth reporting to WRI, even if it's not exactly a bug.  They might be able to fix the problem in a future version.

One can modify Anton Antonov's tracing code posted in his answer to [Determining which rule NIntegrate selects automatically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26401/determining-which-rule-nintegrate-selects-automatically/96663#96663) to construct a rudimentary profiling tool.  Anton expresses some reservations about his code, so you should read his post before using the code below.  It generates a moderate amount of output, but it would make this a very large answer to include it all.
What I will do is summarize the evidence and give the code to generate it.

### Issues with the integrand

The OP's interpolating function is an exact symbolic interpolating function.  It takes several seconds to create it.  Perhaps it is needed in that form, but if machine-precision numerical evaluation is the only purpose, it would be better (from the point of view of speed) to create it as a machine-precision function.  Apparently there is only a speed issue in V10.  One can get around it in V10 by protecting the interpolating function with `?NumericQ`.  One recovers timings similar to V9 this way, which suggests that it is not the oscillatory behavior of the integrand that is causing the slow evaluation.

```
f = Interpolation[Table[{x, Cos[x 100]}, {x, 0, π, 10^-6}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
fN = Interpolation[Table[{x, Cos[x 100]}, {x, 0., π, 10^-6}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
fNQ[x_?NumericQ] := f[x];
fNNQ[x_?NumericQ] := fN[x];
(*
  {21.0106, Null}
  {9.84533, Null}
*)

ByteCount[f]
ByteCount[fN]
(* V9
    904756768  -- f   0.9 GB
     75399504  -- fN
   V10.3.1
    703705096  -- f   0.7 GB
     75399608  -- fN
*)
```

*Tangential remark?* One difference in how V9 and V10 treats interpolating functions is how they are typeset.  This shouldn't affect `NIntegrate`, but maybe the underlying causes are related.  The difference is time is amazing.  Create two input cells as below, select both cells, and execute them simultaneously (shift-return).  Make sure `$HistoryLength` is at least `2`.

```
(* cell 1 *)
SessionTime[]
f[x] // AbsoluteTiming

(* cell 2 *)
SessionTime[] - %%
```

The second cell won't be executed until the output from the first cell is done typesetting.  The timing from `AbsoluteTiming` is the same in V9 and V10, about `4.*10^-6`.  But the wall-clock time between executing the cells, roughly the time spent typesetting, is about 20 times longer in V10.

```
(* Differences in session time *)
0.147116  -- V9
3.362884  -- V10.3.1
```

#### Timings of the four integrands

Running the OP's `NIntegrate` command on the four functions `{f, fN, fNQ, fNNQ}` yields the following timings. In V10, the second time the timings are run, there is a speed-up of both `f` and `fN`.  All subsequent timings are like the 2nd.  The first timing for `f` can range from 4 to 10 seconds; the second is around 2 seconds.  The results for `fN` seem to be consistently as shown.  Note that if the order is changed to `{fNQ, fNNQ, f, fN}` in the `Table`, the timings do not change.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All eight integrations evaluate the functions at `165` points (obtained via `EvaluationMonitor`).  The numeric interpolating function `fN` is much faster than `f`, but V10 still lags way behind V9.  The `?NumericQ` functions `fNQ` and `fNNQ` are much more competitive with V9, although they are consistently slower.

#### Dependence on the number of evaluations

Until the number of evaluations grows large enough, the initialization time dominates.  Note that the increases in time from the `n = 515` to `n = 1027` evaluations are about the same in V9 and V10.  That suggests that the evaluation of the interpolating function is not the issue.  (The results below were run with

```
npts = 0;
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 30 π/400}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, 
   Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> gkpts}}, MaxRecursion -> 0
 EvaluationMonitor :> ++npts] // AbsoluteTiming
```

for `gkpts` in `1 + {8, 32, 128, 256, 512}`.)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Profiling the initialization of `NIntegrate`

Using `SessionTime[]` in the code shown down below, we can print the elapsed time for each step in the initialization of the integration of the OP's `f[x]`.  The timings below show that about 2 seconds are taken to start the integration in V10.  In V9, it is similar in that the initialization takes up almost all the time it takes to evaluate the integral, namely about 0.13 seconds for initialization.

```
(* V10
  time    : step

  0.000696: UpValue call for: NIntegrate`AutomaticStrategy :: 
             {GlobalAdaptive,SymbolicProcessing->0}

  2.108061: UpValue call for: NIntegrate`GeneralRule ...

  2.108530: UpValue call for: NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRule ...

  2.109095: UpValue call for: NIntegrate`GlobalAdaptive ...
*)
```

I don't know how to figure out what happens between the first two steps.  One can omit the `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0` option to see that much, if not all, symbolic processing steps are omitted.  Even with `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0`, `NIntegrate` symbolically evaluated the integrand (for instance, [to see if the integrand is a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77589/nintegrate-over-a-list-of-functions), which it has to do even if `"SymbolicProcessing"` is turned off).

#### Profiling code

Note the profiling code below changes the definition of internal functions used by `NIntegrate`.  Use `Quit[]` to reset.  Do not execute more than once (nothing really bad will happen; `Quit[]` will still work and reset). Note the code uses the global symbol `tmark` to mark the time the computation starts.  This has to be set by the user at the beginning of the computation like this:

```
tmark = SessionTime[];
NIntegrate[...]
```

Profiling code

```
symbNames = Names["NIntegrate`*"];
symbNames = 
  Append[Pick[symbNames, 
    StringMatchQ[
     symbNames, (__ ~~ "Rule") | (__ ~~ 
        "Global" | "Local" | "MonteCarlo" | "Principal" | "Levin" | 
         "Osc" ~~ ___)]], "NIntegrate`AutomaticStrategy"];
symbs = ToExpression[#] & /@ symbNames;
dvs = DownValues /@ symbs;
uvs = UpValues /@ symbs;
Unprotect /@ symbs;
dvsNew = MapThread[
   With[{s = #2},
     DownValues[s] = 
      ReplaceAll[#1, 
       HoldPattern[
         a_ :> b___] :> (a :> (Print[SessionTime[] - tmark, 
            ": DownValue call for: ", Style[s, Red]]; b))]] &, {dvs, 
    symbs, symbNames}];
uvsNew = MapThread[
   With[{s = #2},
     UpValues[s] =
      ReplaceAll[#1,
       HoldPattern[Block[vars_, CompoundExpression[b___]]] :>
        Block[{res = Block[vars, CompoundExpression[b]]}, 
         Print[SessionTime[] - tmark, ": UpValue call for: ", 
          Style[s, Blue], Style[" ::\n", Blue], res]; res]
       ]
     ] &, {uvs, symbs, symbNames}];
```

I used this little utility function to time the integrals for the various integrands.  It sets the global symbol `tmark` to mark the time the computation starts.  It is set up for this particular problem. For instance the value of the integral of the function that is being interpolated is `-1/100`, so the `+ 1/100` lets me see slight changes in the computed value, if any.

```
ClearAll[timeNI];
SetAttributes[timeNI, HoldAll];
timeNI[fn_, opts___] := Module[{npts},
  List[
   $Version,
   tmark = SessionTime[];
   npts = 0;
   (NIntegrate[fn, {x, 0, 30 π/400}, opts, 
       Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0},
       EvaluationMonitor :> ++npts] + 1/100) // AbsoluteTiming,
   Row[{npts, " points"}]
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your deep analysis! I will check the hints and see  how they work with my code.

Comment: @Frederico  You're welcome. Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelE2 If you skip the command `symbNames = Append[Pick[symbNames, ... ` you might be able to see what is happening between `NIntegrate`AutomaticStrategy` and `NIntegrate`GeneralRule`. (Sorry, I can't spent time today to check it myself.) Impressive work!

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks. I gave your suggestion a once-through and there's still a 2-sec. gap between ``NIntegrate`AutomaticStrategy`` and the next call, ``NIntegrate`GetMethodOptionValues``. It is all quite fast from that point on.

Comment: FWIW, `AbsoluteTiming[InterpolatingFunction @@ f]` takes about 1.5 sec.  So if a reevaluation of `f` is triggered inside `NIntegrate`, it would account for at least 75% of the slowdown.