# Can we link Mathematica and Fortran with WSTP?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, fortran

How to link Mathematica and Fortran with WSTP?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, I have done that in the past, but it is tedious. Why not use the simpler approach using [LibraryLink](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38125/29) ? On which operating system do you want to do that?

Comment: Both the LibraryLink and MathLink ( = WSTP) APIs are C language APIs. What you need to figure out is how to call C functions from Fortran. Then you can use the MathLink API from Fortran. However, it might be easier to do the reverse: learn how to call your Fortran library from C and write the glue code in C (either using MathLink, or as Rolf said, using LibraryLink). I suggest you start by learning how to do this in pure C first. Once that's done, hook up the Fortran functions.

Comment: At that time I used iso_c_binding, see e.g. [this] (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperable-Subroutines-and-Functions.html). It is possible, but not so easy.

Comment: @RolfMertig [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199447). OP insists in calling high level _Mathematica_ functions from FORTRAN. IIRC, this is not possible with LibraryLink.

Comment: I am not sure why you tagged this `mathematica-online`. If that's what you're using, then the simple answer is that it's not possible. Please address Henrik's comment above and explain what you want to do precisely.

Comment: Basically i want to call a function of mathematica called Global Adaptive method to integrate a function numerically in fortran code. So is that possible anyhow?

Comment: @PrabhakarNamdev you could do it via a System call and wolframscript as a poor man’s version of MathLink

Comment: can we call NIntegrate function of mathematica from external program with mathlink?