# Nested Numerical Integration

Tags: numerical-integration

So I am trying to evalute the following Integral Numerically:

$$\int_{\mathcal{J}^+(x_0)\cap\mathcal{J}^-(x_f)}^{}A(x_0,x_1)\int_{\mathcal{J}^+(x_1)\cap\mathcal{J}^-(x_f)}^{}A(x_1,x_2) dx_1dx_2$$

The difficulty I have here is that the first integration is used as a limit in the second integration.

I tried the following, but I get a message that the bounds cannot be evaluated:

```
NIntegrate[amplitude[x1, x2]*
NIntegrate[amplitude[x2, x3], {x3, lowerb[x2, xf], upperb[x2, xf]}],
{x2, lowerb[x1, xf], upperb[x1, xf]}]

x3 = Max[-1.,-1.+x2] is not a valid limit of integration
```

The functions lowerb and upperb calculate the lower and upper bound of the integration region correctly.

I think this has to do with the fact that it doesn't evaluate x2 till the first loop has ended.

Comment: Give us some numbers for `lowerb`, `upperb`, `xf`, and a possible form of amplitude to play with...

Comment: I think this is a dup: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10533/nested-nintegrate