# How to improve the speed of this nested NIntegrate?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have an integral that needs to be evaluated using NIntegrate:
$$\int_0^{10}\mathrm{d}x_1\int_0^{10}\mathrm{d}x_2\left(1+(x_2-x_1)^2\right)^{-1/6}\mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^{x_1}\mathrm{d}x'\int_0^{x_1}\mathrm{d}x''f(x'-x'')-\int_0^{x_2}\mathrm{d}x'\int_0^{x_2}\mathrm{d}x''f(x'-x'')}\times\int_0^{x_1}\mathrm{d}x'\int_0^{x_1}\mathrm{d}x''f(x_1-x')f(x_2-x''),$$
where $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{1/3}}.$$

If I follow the instruction given in [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10533/nested-nintegrate), the computational time it takes is too much. Is there any way to improve the computational time?

Here is the code:

```
f[x_]:=1/(1+x^2)^(1/3);

i1[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ] :=  i1[x1, x2] = 
NIntegrate[f[z1 - z2], {z1, 0, x1}, {z2, 0, x1}];

i2[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ] := 
  i2[x1, x2] = 
   NIntegrate[f[z1 - z2], {z1, 0, x2}, {z2, 0, x2}];


    NIntegrate[((1+(x2-x1)^2)^(-1/6)Exp[(i1[x1, x2] + i2[x1, x2])]f[x1-z1]*
f[x2-z2], {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10},{z1,0,x1},{z2,0,x1}];
```

Comment: Am I the only one who hates the notation with the differential operator in front of the integrand? This looks like four integrals multiplied together. Please post the code that takes too much time.

Comment: @george2079 I hate the non-italic differential $d$, which seems to me to be a recent invention of LaTeX-addled minds (compare with plain TeX, *TeXBook*, p. 169, as well as the few centuries of printing pre-2000). The "wrong" order is standard in physics, I believe.

Comment: A few issues, what is `f[0,..]` ?  You have unbalanced parenthesis in last expression.  If you are trying to use memoization the second `:=` should just be `=`

Comment: Sorry? There should be no f[0,..]. It is just f[x]. I have fixed that.

Comment: What do you mean? In the last NIntegrate, I have {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}, which is for the outer integral over x1 and x2.

Comment: @MichaelE2 But according to http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf, you *have* to set it in Roman.  But I agree: I hate that rule.

Comment: They also say "the strength of TeX...lies in the ability to typeset **beautiful** mathematics" -- The ISO was written by an illiterate committee, which was more concerned with rules. Those who make up the rules are always right, by definition. It's the rule. :)  - How many books use an upright d before then, though?

Answer (score 3):

there is one more analytic integral we can pull out:

(using @BobHanlon's `i[x]`):

```
g[x1_, x2_] = 
  Assuming[{x1 > 0, x2 > 0}, 
   Integrate[f[x1 - z1]*f[x2 - z2], {z1, 0, x1}, {z2, 0, x1}]];
NIntegrate[(1 + (x2 - x1)^2)^(-1/6) Exp[-(i[x1] + i[x2])]
     g[x1, x2] , {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.30975, 0.355381}

BTW all the other x1/x2 symmetry in the formulation makes me wonder if one of those `x1` integration limits should be an `x2` (of course I have no idea what the actual calculation is)

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] = (1 + x^2)^(-1/3);
```

Use `Integrate` rather than `NIntegrate` for `i1` and `i2`.

```
Clear[i, i1, i2]

i[x_] = Assuming[{x > 0},
  Integrate[f[z1 - z2], {z1, 0, x}, {z2, 0, x}]]

(*  1/2 (3 - 3 (1 + x^2)^(2/3) + 4 x^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 3/2, -x^2])  *)
```

You are missing a minus sign in the exponential

```
NIntegrate[(1 + (x2 - x1)^2)^(-1/6) Exp[-(i[x1] + i[x2])] f[x1 - z1]*
   f[x2 - z2], {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}, {z1, 0, x1}, {z2, 0, 
   x1}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {14.2359, 0.355381}  *)
```