# NIntegrate giving error NIntegrate::nlim

Tags: numerical-integration

I need to compute the integral

$$
\int_{\tau_0}^1 d\tau \int_\tau^1 dx\,\,f(x)\,f\negthinspace\left(\frac{\tau}{x}\right)\frac{g(\tau)}{x},
$$

where $\tau_0$ is an explicit real number and $f$ and $g$ are functions. The values of $f$ and $g$ are taken from a text-file (they are not continuous functions). Then, for example, if I type $f(\tau/2)$, Mathematica gives me an error because the function $f$ accepts only numbers.

I tried to use `NIntegrate` but it gives me an error relative to the integration domain of $x$, because $\tau$ is a variable and not a real number.

This is the code I use

```
NIntegrate[xf[0, x, 13000, 2]/x xf[0, t/x, 13000, 2]/(t/x), {x, t, 1.}, {t, 0.5,1.}, MaxRecursion -> 100]
```

where `xf` is the function $f$ and in this case $g(\tau) \equiv 1$. I get the error

> NIntegrate::nlim: x = t is not a valid limit of integration.

How can I do this integration?

Comment: When you say `f` and `g` are taken from a text-file, it makes me think you'll need to either use `Sum` or  `Interpolate` your data to make a continuous function for `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ([10533](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10533/764)).

Comment: Reverse the order of the iterators as in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10535/4999) (the "outside" integral comes first): `NIntegrate[..., {t, 0.5,1.}, {x, t, 1.},...]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you, this solved my question.

Comment: @ChrisK thank you.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ... that is answer to (10533) and thus it is a duplicate?

Comment: @gwr Yes, I was pointing out that an answer that was not the accepted one was what the OP should consider. It could be put on hold as OT, too, since the answer here is the standard way iterators work in *Mathematica*. But I usually prefer "duplicate" to "found in the documentation," when a duplicate exists.