# Difficult definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to compute a numerical value for the following  definite integral:
$$ \int_0^1\int_0^1 e^{-\xi^2+\eta^2}e^{\int_0^{1/2}e^{-2\,\xi\,(1+\cos(3 s))}\eta\sin (\pi s)\,ds}\,d\xi\,d\eta.$$
I wrote in Mathematica the following code:

```
Integrate[Exp[-xi^2 + eta^2]*Exp[Integrate[Exp[-2*xi*(1+Cos[3*s])]*eta*Sin[Pi*s], {s,0, 0.5}]], {xi, 0, 1}, {eta, 0, 1}]
```

I think the problem is the computation of 
$$ \int_0^{1/2}e^{-2\,\xi\,(1+\cos(3 s))}\eta\sin (\pi s)\,ds. $$
Is there a way to compute integrals of the form
$$\int_a^b F(x,y)\,dy $$
in Mathematica? Integrals of the form $\int_a^b F(y)\,dy$ can be computed exactly or numerically, with the Integral or NIntegral functions, but what about $\int_a^b F(x,y)\,dy$ ?

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10533/nested-nintegrate) solve your problem?

Comment: @Mathe172 Yes! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
i1[xi_?NumericQ, eta_?NumericQ] := i1[xi, eta] = NIntegrate[Exp[-2*xi*(1 + Cos[3*s])]*eta*Sin[Pi*s], {s, 0, 0.5}];

NIntegrate[Exp[-xi^2 + eta^2]*Exp[i1[xi, eta]], {xi, 0, 1}, {eta, 0, 1}]
```